# From what directory does eclipse start the jvm?

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

When I run my application through eclipse, is the jvm being started from my projects root directory?

I'm trying to guage why `File file = new File("");` is indeed the root directory of my project. If this is the case, the default classpath for the jvm instance will be my projects root directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the default working directory for your launched JVM is the project's root directory. You can change that in the launch configuration.

The classpath however is different. It defaults to the project's build path (includes all jar files for example). Usually, that would not include the project root directory, but something like 'bin' or 'build' or 'src' (or wherever you compile your classes to). That can also be changed in the launch configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you stats Eclipse,then first it ask you for the Workspace(where you want to set the project source location).there you can put your code source of project.when you run you Application it runs under the JVM(via your default classpath name for jvm).